# JavaScript - Check if input is a number

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm facing the following (basic) problem: I want to check if an input from an HTML-input field is not greater than 5 or not a number. If this is given the function should return true. Otherwise (so if greater than 5 or a number) it should resturn false. The validation if the number is not greater than 5 works fine so far but when I add the typeof-argument this one doesn't works.
This is my code so far, thanks in advance!

```
function isValidStart(start) {
if (start.trim().length > 5 || typeof(start) === 'number') {
   return false
 }
 return true
```

Comment: 1) HTML inputs return a string value. 2) numbers don't have a `trim` method. So, the second condition will never be true 3) Have you checked the value of `start.trim()` and `start.trim().length`? It checks if the string's length is > 5. Please debug your code.

Comment: Look at parseInt() and isNaN()

Comment: (offtopic) Don't use `typeof(start)` - rather `typeof start`

Answer (score 1):

An `Element.value` (input, select, textarea etc) will always be a **String**.

Test if a single-digit integer range is used can be achieved with a small Regex and [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

#### Test an integer of length 5

```js
const isValidStart = v => /^\d{1,5}$/.test(v); // or use [0-5]

console.log(isValidStart("1"))     // true
console.log(isValidStart("55555")) // true
console.log(isValidStart(2))       // true
console.log(isValidStart("a12"))   // false
```

You don't even have to care if a *value* is a String or Number.

#### Single integer:

to match single digits from range 1 to 5:

```js
const isValidStart = v => /^[1-5]$/.test(v); // or use [0-5]

console.log(isValidStart("1")) // true
console.log(isValidStart(2))   // true
console.log(isValidStart("a")) // false
console.log(isValidStart("6")) // false
```

Comment: He said the number `should not be a string` and you are checking for string

Comment: @AhmadHabib I think he actually means: String should noth be Alpha, only Numerical.

Comment: No, his question isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Number.isFinite()` function to check if a variable is a finite number, which in your use case should do the Job.

```
let intVar = 2;
Number.isFinite(intVar);
$true
```

However it looks like your `start` variable is not actually a number as you can't call `.trim()` on a number. So this if statement will never return True.

You should typecast your variable. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
let reg = new RegExp(/^\d{0,5}$/);
    console.log(reg.test('1'));
    console.log(reg.test('12'));
    console.log(reg.test('123'));
    console.log(reg.test('1234'));
    console.log(reg.test('12345'));
    console.log(reg.test('string'));
    console.log(reg.test('124var123'));
```